# Mysql Exclude records from LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that returns all the records from table 1 and all the records from table2 where there is a match BUT exclude records from both tables where a column contains a set content.

```
SELECT h.UniqueID, h.Room, h.AuditBy, h.AuditDate, h.SeqID, h.Stat, h.RepairCode, d.SeqNo, d.SeqHeader, d.SeqText 
FROM  NXLHR_SequenceNo_default d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  NXLHR_Hist_17 h 
ON d.SeqID = h.SeqID AND h.UniqueID = 'NXLHR02571493893502' 
WHERE h.Stat = 1 OR h.Stat = 2 AND RepairCode IS NULL AND h.SeqID != '1306' OR h.SeqID != '1307'
```

At the moment my query retruns records where the column h.SeqID contains '1306' OR h.SeqID contains '1307'

Is there a way to filter out any records where the column SeqID contains either '1306' or '1307'from the result.

My current sample data
[image]

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This sounds like an *inner join*.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: 1) Give sample data for both tables for matching records, which will be used in output. 2) Your expected output based on that

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, you seem to want an inner join.  You have a problem in the `WHERE` clause with parentheses around the conditions -- but this is more easily fixed using `IN` and `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT h.UniqueID, h.Room, h.AuditBy, h.AuditDate, h.SeqID, h.Stat,
       h.RepairCode, d.SeqNo, d.SeqHeader, d.SeqText 
FROM  NXLHR_SequenceNo_default d INNER JOIN
      NXLHR_Hist_17 h 
      ON d.SeqID = h.SeqID AND h.UniqueID = 'NXLHR02571493893502' 
WHERE h.Stat IN (1, 2) AND
      h.RepairCode IS NULL AND
      h.SeqID NOT IN ('SeqID1306', 'SeqID1307') ;
```

Comment: I have added my sample data to the post. Also tried your code using INNER JOIN and NOT IN but I still get the same result i.e the result contains record where the SeqID contains 1306 or 1307. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `SeqID` appears to be a string with a particular format.

Comment: thats my stupid fault for not looking at my query in more detail. That the advantage of having another pair of eyes looking at the issue. Gordon, Many thanks for your help. Fixed and working.